# How can we continue to get the critical points?

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

A service requires the dimensions of a rectangle box are such that the length plus twice the width plus twice the height do not exceed $274cm$ ($l+2w+2h \leq 274$). What is the maximum volume of the box that the service accepts to receive??

That means that we want to maximize $V(l, w, h)=lwh$ subject to $l+2w+2h \leq 274$, right??

To find the critical points we do the following:

$$\nabla V(l, w, h)=\overrightarrow{0} \Rightarrow (wh, lh, lw)=(0, 0, 0)$$

How can we continue to get the critical points??

Comment: I believe you have the correct idea. To find the critical points, you have the relations $wh = 0, lh = 0, lw = 0$. You basically find the critical points that satisfies $l + 2w + 2h < 274$. But from this, you will see that the maximum won't occur in the interior of the region $l+2w+2h \leq 274$.

Comment: Why will the maximum not occur in the interior of the region $l+2w+2h \leq 274$ ?? @MathNewbie

Comment: There's a theorem that states that if there is such a local maximum $x_0$ for $V$ assuming it is differentiable, then $x_0$ is a critical point of $V$. So $\nabla V = 0$ when at least two of $w,l h$ are zero. Combine this with the constraint and you have that the maximum has to be on the surface $l + 2w + 2h = 274$.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see the  Lagrange multipliers of the tag being used, where is the $\lambda$? It is obviously best to use the full $274$, so we maximize $lwh$ subject to $1+2w+2h=274$.

The Lagrangian is $lwh-\lambda(l+2w+2h)$. Set the partial derivatives equal to $0$. We get $wh-\lambda=0$, $lh-2\lambda=0$, $lw-2\lambda=0$. We have the additional equation $l+2w+2h=274$. Solve.

Alternately, we could note that $l=274-2w-2h$, substitute in the expression for $V$, and solve as a $2$ variable maximization problem.

**Amusing fact:** When one does the arithmetic, the maximum volume turns out to be about $190470.6$ cm^$3$. The answer given is $11664$ in$^3$!!

When one converts, one finds that the answer given is approximately right, but not quite. Why did this happen? It turns out that US postal rules for priority mail specify that $l+2w+2h$ must not exceed $108$ inches. And when one does the calculation with $108$, it turns out that the maximum volume is indeed $11664$ in$^3$. But $108$ inches is not exactly $274$ cm, it is $274.32$ cm. The problem was partly translated to metric, but not exactly, and the answer remained in cubic inches.

Comment: Why should we use $l+2w+2h=274$ instead of $l+2w+2h \leq 274$ ??

Comment: We want to maximize volume. It is intuitively clear that it is best to use the full allowance for $l+2w+2h$. If you want to be more formal, suppose best volume was reached at $l+2w+2h=a\lt 274$. Then scaling all dimensions by the factor $\lambda=\frac{274}{a}$, that is, letting $l'=(274/a)l$, and the same for the others, would give us $l'+2w'+2h'=274$ and would multiply the volume by $(274/a)^3\gt 1$.

Comment: I see... The constraint is $g(l, w, h)=l+2w+2h-274=0$. 

We are lookinh for $\lambda$ and $(l, w, h)$ such that 
$$\nabla V(l, w, h)=\lambda \nabla g(l, w, h) \\ g(l, w, h)=0$$ 

$$\Rightarrow (wh, lh, lw)=\lambda (1, 2, 2) \\ l+2w+2h=274$$ 

$$wh=\lambda \ \ , \ \ lh=2 \lambda \ \ , \ \ lw=2 \lambda \ \ , \ \ l+2w+2h=274$$ 

How can we find the values of $\lambda, l, w, h$ ?? 

Can we suppose that they are not equal to $0$ ??

Comment: Any $0$ dimension gives volume $0$, for sure not maximum! To solve, note that $lh=lw=2\lambda$, so $h=w$. Note also that $2wh=lh=2\lambda$, so $l=2w$. So $h=w$ and $l=2w$. We know that $l+2w+2h=274$, so $2w+2w+2w=274$.

Comment: So, we have that $$6w=274 \Rightarrow w=\frac{274}{6} \Rightarrow w=\frac{137}{3}$$ 

So, extrema is $\left (\frac{274}{3}, \frac{137}{3}, \frac{137}{3}\right )$. 

The value of $V$ at this point is $$V\left (\frac{274}{3}, \frac{137}{3}, \frac{137}{3}\right )=\frac{5142706}{27}=190470.5925\dots$$ Is this correct??

Comment: I have not checked the calculator work, but the expression for the maximum volume is correct.

Comment: I got too fancy at explaining why the max is at $l+2w+2h=274$. Suppose we could do best with the sum less than $274$. Make the box a little longer, and we increase the volume. So max volume could not have been reached at $l+2w+2h\lt 274$.

Comment: Ahaaa... Ok... In my book the answer is $11,664  in^3$. So, have I done something wrong?? What is $in^3$ ??

Comment: Sorry, I was away. They gave the units in cm, but the answer is in cubic inches!!! There are $2.54$ cm in an inch. When we divide the answer you got by $(2.54)^3$ we get roughly their answer.

Comment: @MaryStar: The details of why when we convert to cubic inches we get an answer which is close to the book's is kind of funny, so I added a remark to the answer.